# How to get screen position of a Swing element?

Tags: java, swing

how do I get the actual screen position of an element, say a Button? If I use getBounds I get the position relative to the parent container, not the screen...

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Have you tried [`Component.getLocationOnScreen()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen--)?

Answer (score 10):

You can try this:

```
// Convert a coordinate relative to a component's bounds to screen coordinates 
Point pt = new Point(component.getLocation()); 
SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(pt, component);
```