# Java - Screen Coordinates to Image Coordinates

Tags: java, image-processing

I am using a Java application to display an image on the screen. I also am using an eye-tracker device which records the absolute pixel X,Y locations where the person is looking on the screen.

However, what I need to do is convert these X,Y coordinates from the screen positions into the X,Y locations of the image. In other words, somehow I need to figure out that (just an example) 482, 458 translates to pixel 1,1 (the upper left pixel) of the image.

How can I determine the image's placement on the screen (not relative to anything)?

I saw a few posts about "getComponentLocation" and some other APIs, but in my experimentation with these, they seem to be giving coordinates relative to the window. I have also had problems with that because the 1,1 coordinate that they give is within the window, and there is actually a bar at the top of the window (that has the title and the close and minimize buttons) whose width I do not know, so I cannot easily translate.

Surely there must be a way to get the absolute pixel location on the screen of a component?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get screen position of a Swing element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192291/how-to-get-screen-position-of-a-swing-element)

Comment: I think you actually need the reverse of what you said you need. You have screen coordinates, and you need to convert them to component coordinates. Take a look at [SwingUtilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen%28java.awt.Point,%20java.awt.Component%29).

Comment: I think SwingUtilities the convertPointToComponent may be what I need.

Answer (score 4):

If we are talking about Swing/AWT application than class `java.awt.Component` has method `getLocationOnScreen` which seemed to do what you want

And yes as @RealSkeptic mentioned in comments to question:

[SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#convertPointFromScreen-java.awt.Point-java.awt.Component-)

will do all this work for you considering components hierarchy

Comment: I think OP is trying to do the reverse: the coordinates available are on screen, and need to be converted to component space.

Comment: Yes, that's what I am trying to do - convert from screen to component space.

Comment: Ok, but if you know screen coordinates of point and component coordinates on screen than you could subtract component coordinates and get coordinates within component.