# MouseListener across several panels?

Tags: java, swing

My user story is the following:

> In order to upgrade a tower, the player has to drag a gun from the shop and drop it on the tower.

In practice, the `GameView` contains both the `BattlefieldCanvas` and the `ShopView`. Besides, the `ShopView` contains a `GunSelector` for each buyable gun. All those guys are sub-classes of `JPanel`.

I'm currently using a `MousListener` to handle several actions performed on the `BattlefieldCanvas`; I thought I could use the same stuff to handle a mouse trip from one of the `GunSelector` to the `BattlefieldCanvas` ( = across several panels ), so I tried to add the same `MousListener` to the gun selectors and the battlefield.

[image: http://aygix.free.fr/down.php?path=stackoverflow/Odepax/mouse-listener-across-several-panels.png]

Problem: doesn't work. The `getSource()` method of the event object returns a reference to the gun selector while the mouse is actually released on the battlefield.

---

PS: Unlike gun selectors, towers are not swing components but images drawn by the `paintComponent` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) To answer to your original question as to why source is still the component mouse was clicked on. You just need to read the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html#getSource--):

> public Object getSource()
>
> The object on which the Event initially occurred.
>
> Returns:
>       The object on which the **Event initially occurred**.

2) Now, how can we get the actual component that mouse is released on. You can try this approach:

```
@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    Component theCOmponentMouseIsReleasedOn = frame.findComponentAt( e.getLocationOnScreen() );
}
```

You don't need to always call `findComponentAt` on frame, you can call on the container that contains your `BattlefieldCanvas`.

Comment: Thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2192291/how-to-get-screen-position-of-a-swing-element), I eventually managed to get what I wanted overriding `mouseEntered` with `currentView = e.getSource()` and computed the relative mouse location in the `mouseReleased` method making the difference between the absolute position of the component ( `bfLoc = ((BattlefieldCanvas)currentView).getLocationOnScreen()` ) and the mouse absolute position : `new Point2D.Double(e.getXOnScreen() - bfLoc.getX(), e.getYOnScreen() - bfLoc.getY())`.